# Processing data from multiple cells and comparing results with another cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

For most orders, I have multiple deliveries under the same recipient ID and I need to compare **whether everything ordered is really delivered**. All products are divided by a comma and have always the same format. Only thing is there are 4 main types of products divided into 4 columns

The result should either be an `OK`, or an output what and how much is missing

If Excel is easier/better/needed for this job, I can process all the data in Excel without a problem, I just need that thing working somehow :-)

[Here is a link to a dummy sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U4yYfEqout_j6-eqI7idn-perCOccUMVbSLFWDMmHZ0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: so you want OK in H column if all products from B,C,D,E are delivered under same ID?

Comment: Yes, exactly like you said.  
Also all products in B are always only in B nowhere else, the same with C, D, and E.

Comment: Delivered!A3 has same ID as A2 is that as is or a typo that its not joined under same id?

Comment: every row is a separate delivery for the same recipient so every time the recipient ID appears all those rows need to be combined. The issue is that for one order there usually are 2-3 separate part deliveries. Also for ordered 3 pieces of something, in one delivery there could be 1 piece delivered and the rest 2 could be delivered in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EU syntax:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", "&CHAR(10); 1; CONCAT(CONCAT(
 INDEX(QUERY({QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"); "select Col1")\
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "\d+"))}); 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")-
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
 INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"); ; 1);
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( ; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( ; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"); 1; 0); 0); 
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( ; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( ; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"); 2; 0); 0); COUNTA(
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"))/2; 1)}; 
 "select Col2,'x',Col1 where Col2>0 label 'x'''"); ; 1);
 INDEX(QUERY({QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"); "select Col1")\
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "\d+"))}); 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")-
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
 INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"); ; 1);
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( ; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( ; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"); 1; 0); 0); 
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( ; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( ; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"); 2; 0); 0); COUNTA(
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"))/2; 1)}; 
 "select Col2,'x',Col1 where Col2>0 label 'x'''"); ; 2));
 INDEX(QUERY({QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"); "select Col1")\
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "\d+"))}); 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")-
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
 INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"); ; 1);
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( ; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( ; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"); 1; 0); 0); QUERY(
 IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( ; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( ; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"); 2; 0); 0); COUNTA(
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "x(.+)")\
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); "\d+"))}); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null Group by Col1"))/2; 1)}; 
 "select Col2,'x',Col1 where Col2>0 label 'x'''"); ; 3))); "OK"))
```

[image]

## US syntax:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", "&CHAR(10), 1, CONCAT(CONCAT(
 INDEX(QUERY({QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), "select Col1"),
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "\d+"))}), 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")-
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
 INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), , 1),
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( , 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( , 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 1, 0), 0), 
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( , 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( , 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 2, 0), 0), COUNTA(
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"))/2, 1)}, 
 "select Col2,'x',Col1 where Col2>0 label 'x'''"), , 1),
 INDEX(QUERY({QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), "select Col1"),
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "\d+"))}), 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")-
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
 INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), , 1),
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( , 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( , 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 1, 0), 0), 
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( , 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( , 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 2, 0), 0), COUNTA(
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"))/2, 1)}, 
 "select Col2,'x',Col1 where Col2>0 label 'x'''"), , 2)),
 INDEX(QUERY({QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), "select Col1"),
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "\d+"))}), 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")-
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
 INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), , 1),
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( , 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( , 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 1, 0), 0), QUERY(
 IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( , 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN( , 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&
 CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 2, 0), 0), COUNTA(
 QUERY(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "x(.+)"),
 VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")), "\d+"))}), 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null Group by Col1"))/2, 1)}, 
 "select Col2,'x',Col1 where Col2>0 label 'x'''"), , 3))), "OK"))
```

Comment: I might need a little bit of help with making it fit to my spreadsheet, I will message you on your test sheet. Thanks

Comment: This formula is working flawlessly! Everything works automatically (just takes time, of course since it is a complicated formula). The main thing is you have created exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

## `NOTE: This solution works only with unique items`

## US syntax:

```
=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")); TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀", COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("", 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)))-
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")))+1), "♀"))}, 
 "limit "&COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("", 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1))), 0), 
 NOT(COUNTIF(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")); 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀", COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("", 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)))-
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")))+1), "♀"))}, 
 "limit "&COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("", 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1))), 0), 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("", 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1))))), "♂", ""), ))="", 
 "OK", ARRAYFORMULA(textJOIN(", ", 1, SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")); TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀", COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("", 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)))-
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")))+1), "♀"))}, 
 "limit "&COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("", 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1))), 0), 
 NOT(COUNTIF(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")); 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀", COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("", 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1)))-
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2, ", ", ",")), ",")))+1), "♀"))}, 
 "limit "&COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("", 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1))), 0), 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("", 1, ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2, Delivered!$A$2:$E, 2, 0), SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E, Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"), ";"), CHAR(9), " ")}&
 "×"), "  ", ","), ",,", ","), ", ", ","), " ×", ""), "×", ""), ",", 1, 1))))), "♂", ""))))
```

[image]

## EU syntax:

```
=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; 
 SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀"; COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(""; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)))-
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")))+1); "♀"))}; 
 "limit "&COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(""; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1))); 0); 
 NOT(COUNTIF(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀"; COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(""; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)))-
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")))+1); "♀"))}; 
 "limit "&COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(""; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1))); 0); 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(""; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1))))); "♂"; ""); ))=""; 
 "OK"; ARRAYFORMULA(textJOIN(", "; 1; SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; 
 SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀"; COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(""; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)))-
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")))+1); "♀"))}; 
 "limit "&COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(""; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1))); 0); 
 NOT(COUNTIF(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")); 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀"; COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(""; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1)))-
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; SUBSTITUTE(B2:E2; ", "; ",")); ",")))+1); "♀"))}; 
 "limit "&COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(""; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1))); 0); 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(""; 1; ","&
 {VLOOKUP(A2; Delivered!$A$2:$E; 2; 0)\ SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 FILTER(Delivered!$B$2:$E; Delivered!$A$2:$A=A2)&CHAR(9)&";"); ";"); CHAR(9); " ")}&
 "×"); "  "; ","); ",,"; ","); ", "; ","); " ×"; ""); "×"; ""); ","; 1; 1))))); "♂"; ""))))
```

Comment: If I am correct it is not possible to advance the range (amount of deliveries) of this formula easily, right? For example if I need to compare 30 deliveries instead of this exact number that is in the dummy spreadsheet, can I still make it work?

Comment: sure you can, just edit every: `$B$2:$E`, `B2:E2` and `Delivered!$B$2:$E` range... let's say for: `$B$2:$Z`, `B2:Z2` and `Delivered!$B$2:$Z` ...`TEXTJOIN` can work with maximum of 50000 characters

Comment: Is the formula searching for a specific area or the recipient ID in Delivered! ? Because I mostly have each half in a significantly different row number

Comment: no, the formula does not search for anything. it creates two virtual columns (one from Ordered sheet an one from Delivered sheet - while from Delivered sheet it joins all items which are under the same ID) with each item per every row and then it filters out stuff between those two VR columns and joins back the result into a single cell.

Comment: based on similar logic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54795616/5632629

Comment: There seems to be an issue in the comparison because the result is that something what seems to be perfectly OK is supposedly missing. When you said it isn't searching for anything - how does the formula know that it's looking into the correct cells?

Comment: hmm, maybe we used wrong kind of filter - take a look here whats going on and also you can test each kind of filter in TEST sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cpKN4gVPdKJ5TDcEYzNlGDs56hIt2zy-2esEXcTJD_A/edit#gid=199477694

Comment: I've created new and more powerful filter... check it out and let me know if it's working flawlessly

Comment: Hello, sorry for not responding sooner, I was offline for a bit. I will try it and I will let you know what I have found out

Comment: I have looked into your spreadsheet and for now I have some questions just so I understand what am I looking at in separate parts. When you have time, please let me know so we can discuss it a bit. Thank you

Comment: anytime. you can just leave your questions in the sheet if I wouldn't be around